# convert basic RGB to alpha in pygame

Tags: colors, pygame, rgb, alpha

```
light_green = (0,200,0,100)
pygame.draw.rect(game_display,light_green,(50,200,60,110))
```

I know that this has the alpha property in the 4th section(100). But it is not transparent when applied on top of a background. It is simply just a solid square block. I want to be able to see the background through the square. Any help always appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The draw module's functions do not draw transparent. See the [documentation for draw](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html)

> Most of the arguments accept a color argument that is an RGB triplet.
>   These can also accept an RGBA quadruplet. The alpha value will be
>   written directly into the Surface if it contains pixel alphas, **but the
>   draw function will not draw transparently**.

A workaround is to use the respective functions from the `pygame.gfxdraw` module instead, they add transparency, for your case the [`box`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/gfxdraw.html#pygame.gfxdraw.box) function.

```
import pygame.gfxdraw
light_green = (0,200,0,100)
pygame.gfxdraw.box(game_display, pygame.Rect(50,200,60,110), light_green)
```

If you only want to draw rectangles you can as an alternate way directly fill a Surface and blit it to the screen.

```
light_green = (0,200,0,100)
s = pygame.Surface((60, 110), pygame.SRCALPHA)
s.fill(light_green)
game_display.blit(s, (50, 200))
```